# SelectToPdf html to pdf conversion makes the font size slightly smaller. There is a way to configure font size from settings?

Tags: c#, html-pdf, selectpdf

SelectToPdf after conversion from html to pdf makes the font size they way smaller as it should be

I've compared it with some different html-pdf converters and they work as expected

Here are my converter settings

```
            {
                Options =
                {
                    EmbedFonts = true,
                    ExternalLinksEnabled = true,
                    PageBreaksEnhancedAlgorithm = true,
                    RenderingEngine = RenderingEngine.WebKit,
                    MarginTop = 40,
                }
            };
```

It is possible to configure that from the converter settings or that could be configured only from inside the html?

Comment: I had the similar problem with cristal report and resolve  it by setting a value in server registry. Try to set the same as I did.

Comment: @SeyedRaoufModarresi thanks for your suggestion but this didn't help

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you can do this with details from the following link:

https://selectpdf.com/demo/page-settings.aspx

Let me know if this helps

Comment: I've checked that one before. You can apply it only for specific new `PdfTextElement` while I'm trying to convert the whole html with using `converter.ConvertHtmlString(htmlString)`. So that's not what I need exactly, or I'm missing something?

Comment: Ah right yes i see what you mean. looking through the documentation then im not sure it would be possible then unless there is a way you can add the new font and size and then apply it to the pdf.

Answer (score 0):

To increase the overall font size in PDF, you can apply the below style at top of the complete HTLM.

```
<div style="font-size: 1.5em;"> completeHTMLString </div>
```

font-size value can be changed as per need, but keep it in 'em'.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue but was due to the WebPageWidth set too large which caused the font to be smaller due to DPI.

Try setting converter.Options.WebPageWidth to 816 = letter (8.5") at 96 DPI

https://selectpdf.com/docs/P_SelectPdf_HtmlToPdfResult_WebPageSize.htm